# Triangulated Edge Subdiv for Differential Growth in Geometry Nodes - Improvements?

Tags: geometry-nodes, subdivision-surface, extrude, simulation-nodes

I tried to create a Geometry Nodes Tool similar to this destructive Add-on https://github.com/inca/blender-differential-growth

This is related to my question here:
[Capture Top and Side Boolean from former Extrusion to new Geometry (Geometry Nodes)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/312003/capture-top-and-side-boolean-from-former-extrusion-to-new-geometry-geometry-nod)

I succeeded in getting the mesh to sometimes triangulate and thus providing more Geometry to work with (like in the Add-On), but it is doing it for everything at that iteration and not where it is actually needed most, trying to separate the mesh and only triangulating the parts that need it and rejoining with the untriangulated did not work well.

In the .blend-File below I tried to create some guide-curves with a Differential Growth Pattern and thought I could extrude my Mesh with a second Repeat Zone to always snap to these Curves, but it gets confused pretty quickly and messes up.

I don't know if this way of edge subdivision is news but I was pretty happy to have made it work (with the help of @lemon, thank you!) so I thought I would share it here.
I have cleaner Versions of this but some Alpha-Version of Blender messed them up, so I will share them if they work again.

My Question here about Self Collisions is also related to this tool:
[Mesh Self Collision in Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/313761/mesh-self-collision-in-geometry-nodes)

If you have suggestions to improve this, maybe without need for Curves, I would be glad!

Best wishes, Todesdigga

[image]